# Export Apostrophe CMS project

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm having a bit of a hard time exporting my project and running it on another machine. Is there some guide for importing/exporting Apostrophe projects?

`Apostrophe version: 2.46`

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `./scripts/sync-up`; alternatively, you can use `rsync` to sync files and then mongoexport and mongoimport to backup and restore your database

Comment: Thank you @johnspackman but I tried mongodump/mongorestore and mongoexport/mongoimport and the data was in the locally hosted database but only some of it showed on the apostrophe page, which is why it weirded me out ... I tried it with two different projects on more than two different computers with different operating systems. Thanks for your help in this matter, really appreciated!

Comment: Those scripts move lots of production sites around all the time so they should work .. can you be specific about what type of content IS or IS NOT showing up in the second site?

Comment: @StuartRomanek I didn't use the script per se, I wanted to move to locally but on the second website only a couple of images show up and some of the text. Is there a script that does it locally?

Comment: @minter please be precise about what you are doing and share the script you are using if it is not our script.

One possible issue is that the code in your two environments is not the same. If you are not deploying from a git repository, for instance, but are making changes live on two servers, you could wind up in a situation where some templates just don't exist or have the same area names etc. resulting in unrendered content.

Comment: Thanks so much, @TomBoutell, Turns out I just had different versions of the same website (branches) and I hadn't reset the indexes, I read the sync-up script and it was very helpful, thanks!